# C# - Writing a custom Convert.ToInt function/method

Tags: c#, function, methods

Hey guys this is what i got so far:

```
static string ConvertToInt()
{
    string a = Console.ReadLine();
    int num = int.Parse(a);
    Console.WriteLine(num);
    if (int.TryParse(a, out num))
    {
        return a;
    }
    else
    {
        return "-1";
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is to write a custom Convert.ToInt function without actually using the method which is already available in the library. So I tried using int.Parse. It's also supposed to return -1 if the input by the user is NOT a number.

My problem here is that the application simply stops when debugging if I enter "a" and gives me the error that the input string is not in the correct format.

When testing the method, I created a new project with these modifications:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string a = Console.ReadLine();
    int num = int.Parse(a);
    Console.WriteLine(num);
    if (int.TryParse(a, out num))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(a);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("-1");
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And why are you trying to create your own?

Comment: Debugger is always your best friend and at least one debug "session" is greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove the first `Parse` and leave it as `int num;`

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string a = Console.ReadLine();
    int num;
    if (int.TryParse(a, out num))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(a);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("-1");
    }
}
```

Comment: @Bradolf awesome :) would you mind accepting the answer so that the question can be closed?

Comment: Sorry I thought I had to wait at least 15 minutes before I could accept an answer. But it's done now. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 2):

**Problem :** `int.Parse()` throws `FormatException` when string is not in correct format.

**Solution:** remove the `int.Parse()` function and don't assign value to `num` variable

Try This:

```
string a = Console.ReadLine();
int num;
if (int.TryParse(a, out num))
{
    Console.WriteLine(a);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("-1");
}
```

Comment: Y U NO CODEALIGN ?? :)